# Is there a C++ IDE which handles templates well?

Tags: c++, ide

Every IDE I've tried fails to provide code-completion when something template-related is used.
For example,

```
boost::shared_ptr<Object> ptr;
ptr->[cursor is here]
```

Is there IDE that can provide code completion in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually this is a fairly simple template use-case, [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) can handle this easily and more complex template code aswell.

Comment: It fails for the boost::static_pointer_cast<DerivedClass>(baseClassObject)->[cursor is here], where baseClassObject have type BaseClass, and DerivedClass is derived from BaseClass. But, anyway, it is currently the best one.

Comment: You'll always find cases that work in a specific IDE but don't in another. The question is what works in most cases. Qt Creator is an evolving IDE and is free. I'm also quite certain that if you issue a bug on a specific case, such as the one you mentioned with boost::static_pointer_cast it will be addressed.

Comment: What's the connection between "is an evolving IDE" and "is actually a *good* IDE"? If it is evolving, that juts means it might one day *become* good, it certainly doesn't automatically imply that it is good *now*.

Comment: The question here isn't what's a "good" IDE. The author wanted an IDE that handles some particular template code and Qt Creator does that. My comment was merely to show that if there is something Qt Creator doesn't handle, it's likely that it will be fixed since it's in heavy development. Unlike other IDEs (VS) that take years to fix something.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio with Visual Assist X handles that case, but still fails more complex code.

Answer (score 3):

I've always use [Eclipse C/C++ IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/). It supports code completion as well :)

Answer (score 2):

G'day,

As an aside, I'd highly recommend Scott Meyers's excellent "[Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)" book.

Item 49 "Learn to decipher STL-related compiler diagnostics" is worth the price of admission alone! The info therein is also applicable to decoding complex template related diagnostics beyond STL, e.g. for Boost.

Have fun.

BTW +1 for an interesting question.

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse + the CDT plugin will handle this as well as the other tools mentioned

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've just checked. It gives a list of local variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 has significantly improved in this area. There is an open beta going on, you should check it out.

Comment: Been using vs2010 (beta) for a month now, and I'd have to agree!

Answer (score 1):

This works in Eclipse CDT, but you may have to explcitly set the include paths under Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols. Under my env. I had to dig down and explicitly add the include\c++\4.2.1 and include\c++\4.2.1\m68k-elf. Just having the directory specified to the cross compiler root \include did not allow content assist to work. Of course once you add the directories, rebuild the index.

You might need to check your Windows->Preferenes->C/C++->Indexer Cache Limit settings and increase them if they are too small. I have mine set to a max of 256MB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Slickedit (http://www.slickedit.com) handles this pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans sometimes gets it right, but not always. It's non-deterministic: seemingly similar code may get parsed, or not, depending on the whim of the IDE.