# Dynamic method of calling structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I have a project which involves writing a C program for some software used by my company. I want it to be as efficient as possible, but the way the software references the signals I'm working with is a little wonky. I'm working with 4 sets of 96 signals; these signals are grouped into 32 groups with 3 members each. Rather than generic functions to work with these signals (the generic functions exist, but there's no documentation on how they work), the auto-generated header file has defined a group of macros (I think) for each of these groups.

Each of the groups are defined as follows...

```
typedef struct {
//struct members
} AB_A_Group_A_Network
```

Each of those structures have a group of macros(?) defined like this...

```
void AB_A_Group_ZF_Network_Init(AB_A_Group_A_Network *pAbc)
{
    double values[6]
    ...
    pAbc->Member_1 = values[3] //array positions vary
    pAbc->Member_2 = values[4]
    pAbc->Member_3 = values[5]
}
```

The software's tech support suggested I do the following, but I was hoping there'd be a better way to do it. Of course this is a long method, but I can write it with a python script no problem, if need be. These 250+ lines of code will run every second in my application for each data set.

```
AB_A_Group_A_Network GroupA;
AB_A_Group_B_Network GroupB;
//...and so on
AB_A_Group_ZF_Network GroupZF;

AB_A_Group_A_Network_Init(&GroupA);
AB_A_Group_B_Network_Init(&GroupB);
//...and so on
AB_A_Group_ZF_Network_Init(&GroupZF);

CD_Array_Set(0,GroupA.Member_1); //a custom array function meant to interface with the software
CD_Array_Set(1,GroupA.Member_2);
//...and so on
CD_Array_Set(95,GroupZF.Member_96);

//...Repeat 3 times for 4 sets of data (Data sets A-D), with checks to see if that data exists
```

I thought of doing something like this, but I'm not sure you can use char arrays in this way. I'll add the disclaimer don't have much experience with C, so this might look/sound really stupid. This isn't working code, just a stream of consciousness. I'm also not sure if doing it in this way, if possible, would just end up losing efficiency. I'm completely open to other methods.

```
char groupName[70] = "AB_*_Group_*_Network";
char dataset = 'A';
char group = 'A';
char member = '1';
char groupInit[70]

//write a loop to increment dataset alphabetically
//check if dataset exists
groupName[3] = dataset;

//write a sub-loop to increment group alphabetically (each set has 32 groups)
groupName[27] = group;

//use groupName in place of struct name (not sure how or if this is possible with my current methods)

groupInit = strncat(groupName, "_Init", 5);

//use groupInit in place of _init macro name

//write a sub-loop to increment member numerically (each group has 3 members)
char member[10] = "Member_*";
member[7] = member;

CD_Array_Set(i,groupName.member);
```

Is the long method really the best way of doing this? Any advice you can offer is appreciated!

Comment: You can't refer to variables and types dynamically from strings. These names are all resolved at compile time.

Comment: What you could look into is macros with token pasting, so you don't have to repeat all the common parts of each variable declaration and initialization.

Comment: How different is `AB_A_Group_A_Network` to `AB_A_Group_B_Network` to `AB_D_Group_ZF_Network` etc.? It seems strange to `typedef` a `struct` you only use once. An array of identical structs (with function pointers and `union`s as required) could simplify the problem into a couple of loops.

Comment: "`CD_Array_Set(95,GroupZF.Member_96);`" contradicts "signals are grouped into 32 groups with 3 members each". Should it be `95%3=2` i.e. `CD_Array_Set(95,GroupZF.Member_2);`?

Comment: @LegendofPedro Each of them are pretty much exactly the same, with some variation on exactly where each of the members sits in values[]. The support files in my project are computer-generated, and there are structures in the file that look nothing like this; I'm assuming the devs were just making the software as flexible as possible. Do structs generally go nicely into arrays?

Comment: @LegendofPedro The 'groups' really just refer the way that the members are stored in the program. Each group utilizes some bytes of storage, and each member takes up an amount of those bytes. It's weird, I'll give you that, but the signals all belong to the same set of data, so they are numbered 1 to 96.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to refer to variables and type names dynamically from strings at runtime. But you can use token pasting in a macro to avoid all the repeated code.

```
#define INIT_GROUP(dataset, group) \
AB_ ## dataset ## _Group_ ## group ## _Network Group ## group; \
AB_ ## dataset ## _Group_ ## group ## _Network_Init(&Group ## group); \
CD_Array_Set(0,Group ## group .Member_1); \
CD_Array_Set(1,Group ## group .Member_2); \
...
CD_Array_Set(95,Group ## group .Member_96);
```

Unfortunately, there are no loops in the preprocessor, so you have to write all 96 `CD_Array_Set` lines in the macro.

With this macro, you can then write:

```
INIT_GROUP(A, A)
INIT_GROUP(A, B)
...
INIT_GROUP(A, ZF)
```

Comment: This answer is really helpful! By "no loops in the preprocessor", do you mean that I could not replace the 0 in `CD_Array_Set(0,Group  ##group .Member_1)` with a variable? How does that number or line differ from the other lines I am replacing? Also, with this method, it seems I can write a loop with the line `INIT_GROUP(i, j)`, as long as I set the arrays separately. Is this correct?

Comment: Variables don't get values until the program is running, macros are expanded when you're compiling.

Comment: `INIT_GROUP(i, j)` will expand into `AB_i_Group_j_Network Groupj; ...`. The variables will just be incorporated textually, not their values.

Answer (score -1):

### Auto generated C code

It is possible to do such things in C but it requires *ugly* Macros.

First thing i would look at is

> An old Stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12591965/8964221
>
> And the mentioned gist in it: https://gist.github.com/epatel/3786323

**BUT!**
I would think about the time it would consume to have it bug free and working.
It won`t be that easy to transform it to ur needs.